# Как сделать ширину input by content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Растягивать ширину инпута под значение инпута не используя посторонние блоки. Один из кейсов который не подходит это использовать див\спан заталкивать туда значение и брать у него ширину.

Comment: это результат действия бредогенератора или я дебил?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как вариант можете воспользоваться не инпутом, а дивом с contenteditable="true"

```css
.look-like-input{display: inline-block; padding: 7px; border: 1px solid grey;}
```

```html
<div class="look-like-input" contenteditable="true">Я редактируюсь</div>
```

Comment: Столько эмоций, столько эмоций... это ж даже ie8 (http://caniuse.com/#search=contenteditable) поддерживает.